# iOS application is not working on xCode with iOS 5.1

Tags: ios5, ios5.1

I am developing a application in iOS which compile on iOS 5.0 perfectly .But Unable to compile on xCode on iOS 5.1 .The fallowing problem is arising.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RFAPITests in RFAPITests.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RFAPITests in RFAPITests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

This is a linker problem.  The code or library that defines `SenTestCase` needs to be added to the appropriate compile or link phase for your target depending on whether it's in source or binary form.